# Stop modal from closing on outside click or esc

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi im trying to disable outside click in my modal. I've tried using methods like backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false but i cant seem to make it work

html:

```
<div class="container my-5">


<hr class="my-5">


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data- 
keyboard="false">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <center><h1 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Want more?</h1></center>
      
      

        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <strong>Create an account or Log in to see additional search results...</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sign up</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

javascript:

```
  $(function() {
  $('#basicExampleModal').modal('show');
  });
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any modal in your code here https://jsfiddle.net/0y395mbr/ Can you explain exactly what is wrong?

Comment: @MFerguson I'm trying to disable outside click (closing the modal) i want the modal to stop the user from using the page unless using the suggested buttons

Comment: [The center element is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Don't use it. Bootstrap offers several ways to center things, so you don't need it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple syntax issues in the code you posted. Ex. extra `</button>` tag and `data- keyboard="false">` has a space in it.  Aside from the syntax issues, it should work as expected as you can see from below example.  If it still doesn't work on your end, there is something else wrong elsewhere in your code.

```js
$('#basicExampleModal').modal('show');
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container my-5">
    <hr class="my-5">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <center>
              <h1 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Want more?</h1>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <strong>Create an account or Log in to see additional search results...</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sign up</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "data-bs-backdrop" and "data-bs-keyboard" attributes instead of data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false". Bootstrap 5 has made changes to the naming conventions, and the data-backdrop and data-keyboard attributes are now prefixed with bs-.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$(function() {
$('modal_id').modal('show');
$('modal_id').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static'
  })
});
```

This script will now allow close the modal by clicking outside the modal or by pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Since, it was my first one I had no idea regarding things.....from now i will try to take care of such things also.